# is exception a subclass of error?

Tags: java, exception

is exception a subclass of error?

Comment: This could have been answered by checking the API doc quicker than asking the question here.

Comment: But he wouldn't have got 7 nearly identical answers then!

Answer (score 8):

No

```
java.lang
Class Exception

java.lang.Object
  extended by java.lang.Throwable
      extended by java.lang.Exception
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Answer (score 7):

This should answer it

[image]
<sub>(source: [javamex.com](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/ExceptionHierarchy.png))</sub>

> Types in red, and their subclasses, are unchecked.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to check:
Exception extends Throwable, and also Error extends Throwable.
So the answer to your question is - no.

Answer (score 3):

No. [Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and [Error](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) both Subclass [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). The difference is that an Error represents such a fatal crash that a program should not even try and catch it. Exceptions should be caught and handled.

Answer (score 1):

No. [Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and [Error](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) are both subclasses of [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).

Answer (score 0):

No.
See apidoc of [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).